# Find maximum of minimum of the distance of an array and 2 numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

We have an array A of size n and 2 numbers x1, x2.
d1(m) = number of elements in A between x1 and m.
d2(m) = number of elements in A between x2 and m.
How to find max(min(d1(A[i]),d1(A[i]))) where i is element of {0,1..,n-1} with a linear worst case algorithm?
My attempt is to have 2 auxiliary arrays for storing the difference of each element from the x1, x2 respectively. Then, I iterate over these 2 arrays, starting max-difference value for both sign. However, I am confused in the part of minimum of maximum. I can take the max of d1 and d2 seperately but not understand how to find max of min

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: I think you're solving the problem in the wrong order - it's requesting that you compute `max( min( d1(A[i]), d2(A[i]) ) for all i )`. Doing this naively would involve computing `d1()`, `d2()` of each `A[i]`, then computing the minimum of each. You could define an array `B` where `B[i] = min(d1(A[i], d2(A[i]))`. Finally, you're supposed to return the single, maximum value among all of these minimums, or `max(B)`. It looks like you're trying to compute maximal differences first then compute a minimum, which doesn't seem to yield the right result.

Comment: If you created a function `minD1(A, m, x1, x2)` that returned the minimum of `d1(A, m, x1) `and `d1(A, m, x2)`, then you should be able to determine the max of that in a loop of all m values (0..n-1) without creating an intermediate array.